# Xamarin. Apple Watch App. Is there an emulator?

Tags: xamarin, apple-watch

Visual Studio 2019 / Xamarin.

There does not seem to be an emulator for Apple Watch?  Android Watch and both phone types are available.

Does anyone know how to install an Apple Watch emulator or am I missing something?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running_your_app_in_the_simulator_or_on_a_device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a try with this [Sample project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/watchos-watchkitcatalog/) . Right click your solution as follow ：

[image]

and select **Properties** option :

[image]

In **Startup Project** , selcet **WatchApp3**(ProjectName) as Startup . Then **Apply** to close window .

[image]

Now you will see Simulator device lists in Visual Studio as follow :

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Marked as answer.  Thanks.